# should two FireFox browsers on same computer share same cookies?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, cookies

I am observing two FireFoxes running on same Windows-7 computer to be sharing same cookies, using JavaScript.

How do two instances of Chrome, IE, etc behave?

Can a browser be forced to allocate its own, private cookie memory?

Comment: Usually the application files and the user files are separate. So any Firefox running in the same user would save information to the same place. I suppose you could run them under two different users, but I'm not sure how Windows works in that respect.

Comment: From what perspective are you asking this question?  As a web developer, a user, or a desktop app developer?  If it’s as a user, then this question belongs rather on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Firefox uses user profiles. As long as the instances are using the same profile, cookies will be shared. Same goes for Chrome. I am not sure about IE profiles, though (and whether it even has them).

Learn more about [Firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) and [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) Profiles.